# Mediarecorder start failed - 19

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, front-camera

I am getting Mediarecorder start failed - 19 error when running start() for MediaRecorder,This happens only when i'm trying to set the camera to capture from front camera with this code:

```
    private Camera openFrontFacingCamera()
{
    int cameraCount = 0;
    Camera cam = null;
    Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
    cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for ( int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++ ) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo( camIdx, cameraInfo );
        if ( cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT  ) {
            try {
                cam = Camera.open( camIdx );
            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                Log.e("my tag", "Camera failed to open: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    }

    return cam;
}
```

this is my startRecording function:

```
    public void startRecording() throws IOException
{
    mCamera = openFrontFacingCamera();
    mrec = new MediaRecorder();  // Works well
    mCamera.unlock();

    mrec.setCamera(mCamera);

    mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
    mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);

    mrec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
    mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());

    //Toast.makeText(this,Integer.toString(Date),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    String time = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+ "/" + getString(R.string.app_name)+ "/" + DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(new Date()).trim() + ".3gp";

    File directory = new File(time).getParentFile();
    if (!directory.exists() && !directory.mkdirs()) {
        throw new IOException("Path to file could not be created.");
    }

    mrec.setOutputFile(time);

    mrec.prepare();
    mrec.start();
}
```

and the Error:

```
10-04 10:52:29.488 15546-15546/com.didi.***** E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
10-04 10:52:29.488 15546-15546/com.didi.***** E/AndroidRuntime:at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code before **mCamera.unlock()**.

```
 try {
    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
 } catch (java.io.IOException e) {

 }
 mCamera.stopPreview();
```

and try following code instead of the **mrec.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));**

```
mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
mrec.setMaxDuration(VIDEO_DURATION);
mrec.setVideoFrameRate(VIDEO_FRAME_RATE);
mrec.setVideoEncodingBitRate(VIDEO_ENCODING_BIT_RATE);
mrec.setVideoSize(VIDEO_SIZE_WIDth, VIDEO_SIZE_HEIGHT);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem as follow tips: 1.Clean my project in build; 2.I change setAudioSamplingRate(10) to setAudioSamplingRate(8000),May be it's too small for the rate to record